# PostgreSQL: Add timezone to columns without converting the times

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a table with several timestamp columns, basically as follows:

```
         timestamp_utc        |          timestamp
------------------------------------------------------------
'2020-10-28 08:00:00.000'     | '2020-10-28 04:00:00.000'
```

I know that the first column is in UTC time, while the second is in NY time. I was wondering how I can add the respective timezone. So the result I would like to have it is something like:

```
         timestamp_utc        |          timestamp
------------------------------------------------------------
'2020-10-28 08:00:00.000Z'     | '2020-10-28 04:00:00.000-04'
```

I have tried doing things like:

```
>>> select timestamp_utc AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' from table;

'2020-10-28 04:00:00.000-04' /* wrong */
```

```
>>> select timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'EST' from table;

'2020-10-28 05:00:00.000-04' /* wrong, it should be 04:00:00 */
```

So finally tried this for the NY part:

```
>>> select timestamp_est AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' from table;

'2020-10-28 04:00:00.000-04'
```

So I think when I add the timezone with the location, it works. However, when I try to do with true timezones it is converting the time in addition to adding the timezone?

Comment: What are the types for the columns `timestamp_utc` and `timestamp`(FYI, I would rename that or did you with `timestamp_est`)?  What is the setting `TimeZone` for the server?

Comment: The column names are just dummy examples, so no worries if it is called timestamp. The TimeZone is Est, but I cant change the server time zone. Work around it by using Python instead of PG. As @Laurenz Albe said, probably it cant be done in PG

Comment: I would look at this section [Time Zones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) in the docs. It will help you understand what is going on. Hint your `TimeZone` is not set to `EST`. Second `EST` is really just an offset  not a full time zone, hence the error in your conversion. Lastly, what data type you are storing your values as, timestamp vs timestamptz is important. I use `dateutil` in Python all the the time, but it still depends on the underlying behavior in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that, since PostgreSQL (counter-intuitively) doesn't store the time zone along with a `timestamp with time zone`. This data type is internally stored in UTC, and on display it is converted according to the current setting of the `timezone` parameter.

So there are two ways to store the time zone offset with the timestamp:

1. Add a new column `timezone` that contains the time zone as a string (`Europe/Vienna`) or a number (`2`).
2. Store the timestamp as a string. This is usually a bad idea.

Comment: I would caution against storing the timezone offset (2). As that does NOT take daylight savings (summer time) adjustment into consideration where the appropriate timezone name does.

Comment: @Belayer I agree. I just offered the possibility of using a numeric offset since that seems to be what OP asks for.